# is periodically updating the last changed timestamp of a document without changing the content black hat SEO?

Tags: seo, search-results

What if we changed the **updated time** on some webpages without change the content?  What would be the impact in the search results?

Would it be black hat SEO if the date were updated on daily basis?

Comment: Document inception date is tracked by Google, however changing the date of a website file without changing the content will not help you in any way, and would be a waste of time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Better to refrain from this activity because
1. Google has historic data of each webpage. It can measure the changes made on the page once it is updated. 
2. Changing last modify date is time and resource consuming and won't result in anything fruitful.